# remove root node which have similar name using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i have xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" standalone="yes"?>
<InvoiceTransmission xmlns="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.IATA.com/IATAAviationInvoiceStandard http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <InvoiceTransmission>
        <TransmissionHeader>
            <TransmissionDateTime>xxxx</TransmissionDateTime>
            <Version>xxxx</Version>
            <TransmissionID>xxxxx</TransmissionID>
            <IssuingOrganizationID>xxx</IssuingOrganizationID>
            <BillingCategory>xx</BillingCategory>
        </TransmissionHeader>
        <Invoice>
            <InvoiceHeader>
                <InvoiceNumber>xxxx</InvoiceNumber>
                <InvoiceDate>xxx</InvoiceDate>
                <InvoiceType>xxxx</InvoiceType>
                <LocationCode>xxx</LocationCode>
                <ChargeCategory>xxxx</ChargeCategory>
                <SellerOrganization>
                    <OrganizationID>xxx</OrganizationID>
                    <OrganizationDesignator>xx</OrganizationDesignator>
                    <OrganizationName1>xxxx</OrganizationName1>
                    <ContactName>xxx</ContactName>
                    <Address>
                        <AddressLine1>xxx</AddressLine1>
                        <CityName>xxx</CityName>
                        <CountryCode>xxx</CountryCode>
                        <CountryName>xx</CountryName>
                        <PostalCode>xx</PostalCode>
                    </Address>
                </SellerOrganization>
    </InvoiceTransmission>
</InvoiceTransmission>
```

i have tried to use the xslt code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" standalone="yes"?>
<InvoiceTransmission xmlns="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.IATA.com/IATAAviationInvoiceStandard http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <TransmissionHeader>
        <TransmissionDateTime>xxxx</TransmissionDateTime>
        <Version>xxxx</Version>
        <TransmissionID>xxxxx</TransmissionID>
        <IssuingOrganizationID>xxx</IssuingOrganizationID>
        <BillingCategory>xx</BillingCategory>
    </TransmissionHeader>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceHeader>
            <InvoiceNumber>xxxx</InvoiceNumber>
            <InvoiceDate>xxx</InvoiceDate>
            <InvoiceType>xxxx</InvoiceType>
            <LocationCode>xxx</LocationCode>
            <ChargeCategory>xxxx</ChargeCategory>
            <SellerOrganization>
                <OrganizationID>xxx</OrganizationID>
                <OrganizationDesignator>xx</OrganizationDesignator>
                <OrganizationName1>xxxx</OrganizationName1>
                <ContactName>xxx</ContactName>
                <Address>
                    <AddressLine1>xxx</AddressLine1>
                    <CityName>xxx</CityName>
                    <CountryCode>xxx</CountryCode>
                    <CountryName>xx</CountryName>
                    <PostalCode>xx</PostalCode>
                </Address>
            </SellerOrganization>
</InvoiceTransmission>
```

but its not giving the proper output
but i want my output like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" standalone="yes"?>
<InvoiceTransmission xmlns="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.IATA.com/IATAAviationInvoiceStandard http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <TransmissionHeader>
        <TransmissionDateTime>xxxx</TransmissionDateTime>
        <Version>xxxx</Version>
        <TransmissionID>xxxxx</TransmissionID>
        <IssuingOrganizationID>xxx</IssuingOrganizationID>
        <BillingCategory>xx</BillingCategory>
    </TransmissionHeader>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceHeader>
            <InvoiceNumber>xxxx</InvoiceNumber>
            <InvoiceDate>xxx</InvoiceDate>
            <InvoiceType>xxxx</InvoiceType>
            <LocationCode>xxx</LocationCode>
            <ChargeCategory>xxxx</ChargeCategory>
            <SellerOrganization>
                <OrganizationID>xxx</OrganizationID>
                <OrganizationDesignator>xx</OrganizationDesignator>
                <OrganizationName1>xxxx</OrganizationName1>
                <ContactName>xxx</ContactName>
                <Address>
                    <AddressLine1>xxx</AddressLine1>
                    <CityName>xxx</CityName>
                    <CountryCode>xxx</CountryCode>
                    <CountryName>xx</CountryName>
                    <PostalCode>xx</PostalCode>
                </Address>
            </SellerOrganization>
</InvoiceTransmission>
```

this "InvoiceTransmission" node is repeating two times 
 i want to remove this second time one

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT code you are using, please? Also, can you format your XML so that it is indented, and not a long single line. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to pretty-print your XML files and they all lack some closing tags. Also, your "XSLT" file does look not like one but rather like the output of one, so please include the XSLT file too.